# Rails grouped_options_for_select not populating edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with two fields where the second depends on what was selected in the first dropdown, if I select 'Asia' in the first, then 'Japan' and 'China' appear as options in the second dropdown.

```
    .field
     = f.label :country
     = f.select :country, ['Asia', 'Europe'], :prompt => 'Select One'

   .field
     = f.label :category
     = f.select :category,grouped_options_for_select(MyModel::CATEGORIES, nil, "Please Select")
```

The CATEGORIES variable looks like;

```
CATEGORIES = {
    'Asia'=> [ 'Japan','China'],
    'Europe'=> [ 'Ireland', 'France']
    }
```

This works but when I go the edit page the second dropdown is not pre-populated with the stored value, how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@dax is right but you need to explicitly set the selected value and not just the attribute.  From the api

> selected_key - A value equal to the **value attribute for one of the  tags**, which will have the selected attribute set. Note: It is possible for this value to match multiple options as you might have the same option in multiple groups. Each will then get selected="selected".

Your code should be

```
= f.select :category, grouped_options_for_select(MyModel::CATEGORIES, f.object.category)
```

**EDIT**

The last argument passed to `grouped_options_for_select` should be passed to `select` instead and should be the value of either the `prompt` or `include_blank` option.

```
= f.select :category,
  grouped_options_for_select(MyModel::CATEGORIES, f.object.category),
  { prompt: 'Please select' }, # here goes the select tag options
  { class: 'my-class' }        # here goes the html options
```

Answer (score 0):

you've set the [selected key](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select) to `nil` -

`MyModel::CATEGORIES, # nil #, "Please Select"`

Try changing your code to this:

```
= f.select :category,grouped_options_for_select(MyModel::CATEGORIES, :country, "Please Select")
```

Comment: that doesn't make any difference